# How can I check for variable changes in a System.Windows.Form

Tags: powershell

I am displaying a form that runs another script after a button is clicked. I need to check for the state of the script completion so that I can update the text of the button.

```
$ButtonEmailInfo.Add_Click({
    $ButtonEmailInfo.Text = "Sending info"
    $ButtonEmailInfo.Enabled = $false
    $Form.Refresh()
    Write-Host("Running start-job")
    $global:SendClicked = $true
    $global:SJob = Start-Job -filepath ($path + "\Send-Info.ps1")
    $ButtonEmailInfo.Text = "Info sent"
    $Form.Refresh()
})
```

The problem with the above code is that the button text is set to "Info sent" before the called script Send-Info.ps1 has completed.

I can test $global:SJob.Finished too see if the script has completed but I'm not sure how you do this in a form. Is there the equivalent of an update() method that gets checked periodically?

Thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Register-ObjectEvent` to handle the job and perform an action when it has completed. You would add the following right after you begin the job.

**Edit** You will need to setup a Timer object to update the Window and allow the thread to handle the Event output from Register-ObjectEvent.

```
$global:SJob = Start-Job -filepath ($path + "\Send-Info.ps1")
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $Global:SJob -EventName StateChanged -SourceIdentifier JobWatcher -Action {
    #Job completed actions go here
    Write-Host "Job Completed!"
    # $Event.Sender is the actual job object that you can either remove or retrieve data from
    #Perform cleanup of event subscriber
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $Event.SourceIdentifier
    Remove-Job -Name $Event.SourceIdentifier -Force
}
```

Here is an example that you can run to see it in action without using it in a form that notifies when completed and then proceeds to remove the job and the event subscription.

```
$SJob = Start-Job {start-sleep -seconds 10} -Name TESTJOB
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $SJob -EventName StateChanged -SourceIdentifier JobWatcher -Action {
    #Job completed actions go here
    Write-Host "Job $($Event.Sender.Name) Completed!"
    #Remove job
    Remove-Job $Event.Sender
    #Perform cleanup of event subscriber and its job
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $Event.SourceIdentifier
    Remove-Job -Name $Event.SourceIdentifier -Force
}
```

**Edit** You will need to setup a Timer object to update the Window and allow the thread to handle the Event output from Register-ObjectEvent. Add the following lines to your UI to create the timer as the window loads and a timer stop when it closes.

```
$Window.Add_Loaded({
    ##Configure a timer to refresh window##
    #Create Timer object
    $Script:timer = new-object System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer 
    #Fire off every 5 seconds
    $timer.Interval = [TimeSpan]"0:0:1.00"
    #Add event per tick
    $timer.Add_Tick({
        [Windows.Input.InputEventHandler]{ $Script:Window.UpdateLayout() }
    })
    #Start timer
    $timer.Start()
    If (-NOT $timer.IsEnabled) {
        $Window.Close()
    }

}) 

$Window.Add_Closed({
    $Script:timer.Stop() 
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure the script is working as expected. I don't see the message "Job completed" in the PS window until I close the original script window in which the $ButtonEmailInfo.Add_Click() is called.

Comment: I seem to remember that it would complete if you closed out the window (like it was waiting for access to the thread). Let me dig out some old code and see what I did to get around it.

Comment: Ok, the UI holds the thread that the Window is running under. This means that it will not give it up to the background job or event unless it has something happen, such as updating the window on a timer. I've updated my answer for reference.